# How to convert video file to Base64 string and vice versa?

Tags: android

I want to convert video file to base64 string and vice versa currently my video is inside raw folder .This is my code :

```
String uriPath = "android.resource://com.hello.videouploaddemo/raw/sendvideo";
```

Comment: I want to convert a video file !!

Answer (score 1):

First convert the raw file into a `byte[]`

```
InputStream inStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sendvideo);
byte[] video = new byte[inStream.available()];
```

Use the Android `Base64` Class

`public static byte[] encode (byte[] input, int flags)`

```
byte[] base64 = Base64.encode(video,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

`public static byte[] decode (byte[] input, int offset, int len, int flags)`

```
byte[] rowVideoAgain = Base64.decode(base64,0,base64.length,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html

You should start this in a AsyncTask
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: No dude ,I know about it