# Better alternative to android.utils.Base64 to convert a 10MB video to Base64 String?

Tags: android, base64

What is the most efficient way to convert a 10MB video to a Base64 encoded string ? When I use android.utils.Base64, it is extremely slow at times and the app hangs.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093231/how-to-convert-video-file-to-base64-string-and-vice-versa

Comment: I am already using that method but it is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AsyncTask` or a `Service` in background . So you can't lock main thread. Just call your `Service` , do your work and self kill your `Service` after finish. I think best way is `Service` . You can find information and samples [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) .

Comment: Sorry, I guess my question was not clear. What method should I use to do the Base64 conversion fast ? When I use android.utils.Base64, the conversion is very slow for a 10MB video.

Comment: Yes i understand , i focused here : "it is extremely slow at times and the app hangs". If you dont want lock your app look my advice.

Comment: Note that a Service in itself does not take the work off the main thread. It should spawn its own thread for that.

Comment: Yes i know , if you can look my answer i typed "AysncTask" or a"Service" . He can call any "Asynctask" in a "Service"

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I am using the call in an AsyncTask. My main challenge is to speed up the upload.

Comment: Okey man, Could you please mark any answer from here or type solved . Cuz if anybody come here cant see working solution. Thx

Comment: I still have not got the answer to what I am looking for, a fast alternative to android.utils.Base64 encoding

Comment: I understand . You can edit your question like that "I wanna know if there is any faster alternative of base64 "

Answer (score 0):

This do not have sense convert 10MB video on base64 str... i dont know what you want a video string but... encode video in base64 and decode again, it can take a long time, and usually the final size of your string file is larger than the original video size.

Comment: A common reason would be to send it over the email. Coincidentally 10MB is also the max size of attachment for most email services.

Comment: "and usually the final size of your string file is larger than the original video size." Yeah, always, as base 64 is 1/3rd larger than it's input at 6 bits per byte, vs 8.